# pointer to expensive object as data member in lazy initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11

It is often not recommended to use pointers. However, if I have a data member pointing to or referencing to an expensive object for which this data member doesn't have ownership, and this data member can not be initialized during construction(i.e., make this data member a reference is not a choice).

What better options are there than making it a pointer?

And if I make this data member a pointer, do I still need to write my own copy, assignment constructor and destructor?

Comment: "*for which this data member doesn't have ownership*" Well, first question: who *does* have ownership of the "expensive object"?

Comment: @NicolBolas, some other class.

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be to make the data member a smart pointer ([shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)).

That way you don't have to worry about ownership: you create the expensive object and then pass around the smart pointer as a normal object (copy or reference).

When all the shared_ptr instances pointing to your expensive object are destroyed, the pointed-to object is destroyed as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to use a pointer. A good way to do it is using smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` `std::shared_ptr` .

In most cases, you need at least one contructor for allocating the resource to the smart pointer. Other functions depend.

In all, your class should be a resource managing object for that "expensive object".
Ref: [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)

Comment: please don't even mention `std::auto_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers suggest a `std::shared_ptr` member. That violates the "no ownership" requirement in the question. However, there's another smart pointer, `std::weak_ptr`. This pointer does not cause ownership, and therefore it can *expire*.

Weak pointers have copy constructors and assignment operators, with appropriate semantics. The default methods of your class will use these.

One peculiarity of `weak_ptr` is that you need to *lock* them while using the shared resource, since it would be bad if the resource expired while using them. That's why you can't simply use `operator->`.